# Using typedef with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning at the moment about pointers and lists. I had one question about the typedef keyword.

```
typedef int data;
typedef struct nodo *lista;
struct nodo {
  data el;
  struct nodo *next;
};
```

If I write down:

```
lista l;
```

Is `l` a pointer or a struct type. I want to know the part typedef `struct nodo *lista;` defines `lista` to be a pointer of struct type or a struct?

Comment: Never typedef pointers. You are only making it easier to make mistakes that way. Maybe the only real reason to do that is maybe function pointers.

Comment: I would like to know what does the second line of code make.

Comment: `lista l;` is the same thing as `struct nodo *l;`. Now which one is easier to understand? In the first case you don't know if `l` is a pointer or not, in the second case you know.

Comment: It's curious that the structure definition doesn't use `lista` in place of `struct nodo *`.  Not precisely wrong, but a little unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

After

```
typedef struct nodo *lista;
```

`lista` is another name for `struct nodo *`.

So `lista l;` is the same as `struct nodo *l;`.

Answer (score 1):

It defines `lista` as a *pointer* to a `struct nodo`, because of the `*`.

If it were instead defined as:

```
typedef struct nodo lista;
```

`lista` would be just a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the keyword typedef and you will get a declaration of a pointer to an obejhct of the type struct nodo.

```
struct nodo *lista;
```

When the keyword typedef is used

```
typedef struct nodo *lista;
```

then instead of declaring an object of the type `struct nodo *` you are introducing an alias for the type `struct nodo *`.

So instead of writing for example

```
struct nodo *head;
```

you can write

```
lista head;
```